# Storing documents where they will not be deleted along with app

Tags: ios, file-management

Normally all the document related to an iOS application are stored in a document folder, which is attached to the relevant application. When we delete the application, that document folder also gets deleted. What I want to do is store all documents related to that application in a shared folder which will remain the same even though the application gets deleted from the device. Can I do this? If it is possible, I want to secure that folder so that it is not accessible through iTunes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want to do is store all documents related to that application
>   in a shared folder which will remain the same even though the
>   application gets deleted from the device. Can I do this?

No. At least, you can't do it on the device. Your app only has access to a piece of the file system, and that piece is deleted when the user deletes the app. It's possible that you could store the data in iCloud, especially if you expect the user to have you app installed on other devices.

> If it is possible, I want to secure that folder so that it is not
>   accessible through iTunes.

If you want to prevent the user from accessing the data, your best bet is probably to store the data on your own server. Second best would be to store the data in iCloud or similar and encrypt the data, but that's probably not as reliable. (I expect iCloud is plenty reliable, but you don't have as much control over that as you do over your own server.)

Comment: The problem is I have enterprise license. So I dont publish my app in the appstore. This problem occurs when i need to upgrade the existing app. What i normally do is delete the existing one and install the new one which will delete the document folder. Is there a way to update the existing app rather deleting it. Since i use the enterprice license is it possible

Comment: I believe you should be able to update by simply installing the newer version on the device without first deleting the old version.